# SAS Macro to create multiple data sets

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Good afternoon,
I am decent with SAS but I've never written macros.

I have a DB where I need to break out in separate datasets ID's where the date in a field occurs. E.g. All ID's with a date in Jan 2018 would be one dataset, All ID's  with a date in Feb 2018 would be another data set, so on and so forth. Field name is ZDate.

I found this which seems to do exactly what I want. However I think my date isn't in the correct format. The date I'm pulling is in a timestamp in snowflake and I'm converting it to a date with to_date. It's showing as formatted date (16FEB2020) in the original vintagedata data set but the subsequent data sets are completely blank.

```
%macro month;
%local mindate maxdate i date month ;
proc sql noprint;
select min(ZDate),max(ZDate)
  into :mindate , :maxdate 
  from vintagedata
;
quit;
data 
%do i=0 %to %sysfunc(intck(month,&mindate,&maxdate));
  %let date=%sysfunc(intnx(month,&mindate,&i));
  %let month=%sysfunc(putn(&date,monyy7.));
&month 
%end;
  ;
  set vintagedata;
%do i=0 %to %sysfunc(intck(month,&mindate,&maxdate));
  %let date=%sysfunc(intnx(month,&mindate,&i));
  %let month=%sysfunc(putn(&date,monyy7.));
  if intnx('month',date,0)=&date then output &month ;
%end;
run;
%mend;
%month;
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the site.  You should try to ask your question with actual code, rather than a "ask for help writing code" as that's not really on topic here.  In this case, the best way to go about that is to write the SAS data step [or whatever] that would do one iteration of what you want, and then show what you can for macrotizing that, and ask what to do beyond that.

Comment: FYI  - as posted this isn't really a valid SO question, its for more specific programming questions. You can post questions such as this on communities.sas.com instead though. Review the guidelines here on how to ask a question [ask]

Comment: You might not need to create separate data sets.  A single view `select distinct intnx('month',date,0) as month, id`  might be all you need.

Comment: Updated with some code. Please advise!

Comment: Check the format/type of your data extracted from snowflake once it's in SAS. There's a tendency to bring back dates from DB as datetimes not dates. In that case change the interval for INTCK/INTNX to 'dtmonth' to tell SAS you have a datetime intervals, not date intervals.

Comment: im using the to_date() function for the Zdate in pulling my initial query. Running proc contents on my initial data set shows this field as numeric date9.  I also created a separate query and used intnx to add a day to see if there was an issue with how the date is being stored and it worked as expected. Thoughts?